# scans with asynchbase

Tags: hbase

I'm started to use [asynchbase](https://github.com/stumbleupon/asynchbase) library from StumbleUpon and got some problems with continued asynchronous scans. I wrote this code, based on my understanding of library principles:

```
public class AsyncScanner
    implements Callback<Object, ArrayList<ArrayList<KeyValue>>> {
    private final Scanner scan;

    public AsyncScanner(Scanner scan) {
        this.scan = scan;
    }

    public void start() {
        scan.nextRows().addCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public Object call(ArrayList<ArrayList<KeyValue>> rows) throws Exception {
        if (rows == null) {
            return null;
        }
        // some useful things here
        scan.nextRows().addCallback(this);
        return null;
    }
}
```

But with this code on big scans I've got StackOverflowError:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater$AtomicIntegerFieldUpdaterImpl.compareAndSet(AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater.java:279)
    at com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred.casState(Deferred.java:580)
    at com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred.access$100(Deferred.java:430)
    at com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred$Continue.call(Deferred.java:1342)
    at com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred.doCall(Deferred.java:1262)
    at com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred.runCallbacks(Deferred.java:1241)
    at com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred.access$300(Deferred.java:430)
    at com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred$Continue.call(Deferred.java:1350)
    at com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred.doCall(Deferred.java:1262)
    at com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred.runCallbacks(Deferred.java:1241)
    at com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred.access$300(Deferred.java:430)
    at com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred$Continue.call(Deferred.java:1350)
    <--cut-->
```

I tried to find some working examples of continued scans with asynchbase. OpenTSDB uses synchronous scans with `scanner.nextRows().joinUninterruptibly()`. This code from [HBase svn](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hbase/trunk/hbase-server/src/test/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/PerformanceEvaluation.java?view=markup&pathrev=1352764), looks like mine:

```
    @Override
    void testTimed() {
          scanner.nextRows()
            .addCallback(continueScan)
            .addCallbacks(callback, errback);
        }
```

Also, in async documentation there is such phrase:

> You must not build a cycle of mutually dependant Deferreds, as this would cause an infinite recursion (thankfully, it will quickly fail with a StackOverflowError)

but I think, this is not my case.

I'm planning to trace asynchbase to figure out what's wrong with my code, but if anybody can show me working examples of continued scans, it would be very helpful.

**UPDATE:**
This awkward moment when you posted piece of code without error.
Problem was in caller. I needed to make one scan end exit. I wrote:

```
   Scanner scanner = hclient.newScanner(TABLE);
   <!--cut some initialization--!>
   new AsyncScanner(scanner).start();
   hclient.shutdown().joinUninterruptibly();
```

And this `shutdown()` while scanning were the real problem. If `shutdown()` removed or called after scan finishes, all works just fine.

Sorry for possible wasting your time.

Comment: Could you kindly post your update as an answer and accept it to prevent this question to show in unanswered queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy of update:
This awkward moment when you posted piece of code without error. Problem was in caller. I needed to make one scan end exit. I wrote:

```
Scanner scanner = hclient.newScanner(TABLE);
<!--cut some initialization--!>
new AsyncScanner(scanner).start();
hclient.shutdown().joinUninterruptibly();
```

And this shutdown() while scanning were the real problem. If shutdown() removed or called after scan finishes, all works just fine.

Sorry for possible wasting your time